# Bind a JLabel to a class variable

Tags: java, netbeans-7, jlabel

I use Netbeans 7.2, I have created a form which I named 'Form', in this form there is a label whom variable name is 'label', but if I try to access to this label (Form.label) I get a syntax error, it seems that this class hasn't a static variable called 'label'.How to get it?

PS: I'm very familiar with interface builder in xcode, what I'm asking is the equivalent of binding an outlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too bad, i didn't see that Netbeans generates the class code that I can modify.So the label was inside the class.